# while-loop proposition adding

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I want to make a bit complex code which will advice user to add some products to his cart if his total cost of it lower than his budget, but I've run into a problem that when I enter a small budget amount (which can still include a small product like sauce), the code goes into an infinite loop or just doesn't work, would like to know how to repair my code

```
productlist = ['Sushi', 'Spirulini', 'Sause', 'Cabbage']
pricelist = [56, 31, 4, 9]
totalcost = 0
budget = 10

proposal_list = []
i = 0

while totalcost < budget:
  if i >= len(pricelist):
    i = 0
  elif (pricelist[i] + totalcost) <= budget:
    totalcost += pricelist[i]
    proposal_list.append(productlist[i].lower())
    joint = ', '.join(proposal_list)
    i += 1
  elif (pricelist[i] + totalcost) > budget:
    continue 

print (f'You can also add: {joint} to your cart for a great discount!\nTotal cost will be: {totalcost}')
```

Comment: Your loop has only one exit condition: when `totalcost >= budget`. You are ignoring the second exit condition: when `productlist` and `pricelist` are exhausted.

Comment: I would write this with a `for` loop like `for price, product in zip(pricelist, productlist):`, with a check inside the loop to exit early if `totalcost` gets too big.

Comment: On closer look, I see you are allowing the prices and products to repeat, so @Timus's comment is more relevant than mine.

Comment: Oops, and TImus deleted their comment, which pointed out that both `pricelist[i] + totalcost > budget` and `totalcost < budget` can be true at the same time, so you get caught in a loop where neither `i` nor `totalcost` are changed.

Comment: @chepner, could you please rewrite this code with for loop? I would like too see how it have to look, because I don't use them so often

Comment: I did not see Timus' s comment, but as @chepner mentioned that you are using "pricelist[i] + totalcost > budget and totalcost < budget" both at the same time. So your code only will work with an input like "pricelist = [5, 5, 4, 9]". With this list you escape "(pricelist[i] + totalcost) > budget:" condition in the 2nd loop and it satisfies "totalcost >= budget" (from chepner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you get into a situation where both `totalcost < budget` and `pricelist[i] + totalcost > budget` are true (i.e., you have some money left, but not enough for `productlist[i]`), but you don't change either `i` or `totalcost`, so you loop forever on the fact that you can't afford `prodouctlist[i]`.

At no point do you actually exit the loop when you can no longer afford *any* product; you seem to be assuming that you will be able to spend *exactly* `budget` dollars.

Here's an example, using a `for` loop, that buys as *many* of each item as you can (a *greedy* method), so that you only consider each item once.

```
totalcost = 0

for product, price in zip(productlist, pricelist):
    while totalcost + price <= budget:
        proposal_list.append(product.lower())
        totalcost += price
```

For certain price lists, this will also spend as much of your budget as possible. (This is basically the [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) in another guise.) For other price lists, your approach of trying to buy at least one of each item before reconsidering each item could produce a different result.